# Cron not passing params to PHP script

Tags: cron

I have a cron job set like

```
php /home/novinarb/public_html/index.php --uri="cron/24satahr"
```

but the 'uri' param doesn't get to the php script at all. I also tried without the -- in front of uri but still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say it doesn't get to the PHP script at all, you mean that `var_dump($argv);` is empty inside the PHP script?

Comment: In your php.ini is `register_argc_argv` set to **On**?

Comment: @Femi affirmative, again :) I checked the 'usual suspects' and ended up here, still nothing

Comment: What version of PHP is this, if you don't mind me asking: there were a couple of `argv` bugs in the 4 series, but nothing I'm aware of in the 5 series?

Comment: Also, I guess my answer got deleted. I've no objection to the answer being marked as wrong, or not the solution, but questions in that voice ARE one of the ways I answer. Perhaps I should expand more, but I really didn't think that @Kemo needed a ton more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more robust method would be to accept command-line arguments in your PHP script with [`getopt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) or [`$argv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) and making it executable. An example with `$argv` called `script.php`:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
  if (isset($argv[1])):
    echo $argv[1];
  endif;
?>
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x script.php
```

And execute:

```
./script.php "cron/24satahr"
```

Will output:

```
cron/24satahr
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem but was able to fix it after reading the manual entry for php.

Initially I had something set like:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/php/script.php -c 1426 >> /tmp/script.php.log 2>&1
```

I was able to fix it by changing the line to:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/php/script.php -- -c 1426 >> /tmp/script.php.log 2>&1
```

As per the manual entry the syntax is:

```
php [options] [ -f ] file [[--] args...]
```

Also,

```
 args...        Arguments passed to script. Use '--' args when first argument starts with '-' or script is read from stdin
```

Going by that, my cron command becomes:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/php/script.php -- -c 1426 >> /tmp/script.php.log 2>&1
```

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Is the php script running at all?

I suspect you need to provide the full path to php in your crontab line. Even though cron jobs run as you, they don't have any of your login environment set up; this means they don't have your $PATH.