# PHP not working with CRON

Tags: php, cron

I'm using crontab to call a php script.

In this script there is

```
error_log('test');
```

When the script is executed from http or direct command line like

```
php -f script.php
```

Everything is fine, my error is log.

But when called from cron it's not working.

Here is my cron

```
* * * * * -u www-data /full_path_to/php -f /full_path_to/script.php
```

**Here is what I tried :**

- error_log with arguments :

  ```
  error_log('test', 3, '/full_path_to/error.log');
  ```
- changing error reporting :

  ```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors','On');
  ini_set('error_log', '/full_path_to/error.log');
  ```
- cron call ending with > /full_path_to/error.log 2>&1 (don't know if useful)

For http the error_log path is set from htaccess.
I'm lost with php cli...

I can see the cron execution working every minute (syslog), so it should be a PHP config problem ?

Thanks a lot if you can help.

Edit : Cron is executed with "-u www-data"

Here is the call I see in syslog :

```
CRON[13921]: (www-data) CMD (-u www-data /usr/bin/php -f /fullpath/script.php > /fullpath/error.log 2>&1)
```

Comment: Does the script **only** contain that log line? Or is there more context that you're not showing us? Because in itself, this should work. So that tells me that there's most likely missing context . Most common pitfall is using includes with relative paths.

Comment: Yes, right know there are 4 lines : error reporting lines and error_log.
Creating a file is also not working (I tried fopen/fwrite and also file_put_contents)

Comment: Sounds like a permissions problem then. Try running the cron under a user that has access to the required paths (or as root, but that should be a last resort).

Comment: The cron is running as www-data. This AFAIK the same user running apache. Same user, same group... I'll try to set chmod to 777

Comment: Don't do that, chmod 777 is always a bad idea. *Especially* when it regards web accessible files. Also see [How will a server become vulnerable with chmod 777?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271596/how-will-a-server-become-vulnerable-with-chmod-777)

Comment: It changed nothing :( I if write random error in the script like ZZZ, nothing appears in syslog

Comment: Does the `cron` environment have the same `include path` settings as the `direct command line`? i.e. `path variables` etc.  Display both shell environment settings from inside the script ($_SERVER etc.) - I suspect they are different. Make the cron job settings match and it should work?

Comment: @RyanVincent interesting it could be that

Comment: I have answered a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322682/cron-not-passing-params-to-php-script) Please [check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42533773/6670698)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had in fact two problems :

1) My cron was executed with php.ini for php-cli. I used the -c flag to load the good one.

2) I was relying on $_SERVER to declare important constants using variables that do not exist in cli-mode. Now if these variables are not set I parse commande line vars with `getopt()`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem but was able to fix it after reading the manual entry for php.

Initially I had something set like:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/php/script.php -c 1426 >> /tmp/script.php.log 2>&1
```

I was able to fix it by changing the line to:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/php/script.php -- -c 1426 >> /tmp/script.php.log 2>&1
```

As per the manual entry the syntax is:

```
php [options] [ -f ] file [[--] args...]
```

Also,

```
args...        Arguments passed to script. Use '--' args when first argument starts with '-' or script is read from stdin
```

Going by that, my cron command becomes:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/php/script.php -- -c 1426 >> /tmp/script.php.log 2>&1
```

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You have to be aware that there are **user specific** crontabs and a **system wide** crontab.

When you are logged in as user `foo` and type `crontab -e` in console this will allow you to edit your own user specific crontab. All defined cron tasks will be executed as user `foo`. This is even true for user `root`. AFAIK this way you simply **can not change the user** under which a cron task will be run.

Quite different is the file `/etc/crontab`. This is the system wide crontab. Within that file you can change the user of a cron task like this:

```
* * * * * www-data /full_path_to/php -f /full_path_to/script.php
```