# Why is argv always empty when parameter passed with cron job

Tags: php, cron

My cron job entry looks like this:
/usr/local/bin/php /mydir/cron-jobs/mytest.php param=test

Within my cron job I have tried the following:

```
<?php
var_dump($argv);
if (empty($argv)) {
    echo 'empty';
}
```

and:

```
<?php  
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];  
if (empty($argv)) {
    echo 'empty';
}
```

In both cases $argv is always empty.  Running on php 7.1.  What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron not passing params to PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322682/cron-not-passing-params-to-php-script)

Comment: Check the php.ini , value register_argc_argv needs to be enabled in php.ini

Comment: Thank you Tasos that was the issue.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Tasos - I was incorrect.  The setting was on.  It was further down in my ini file.  It is currently enabled as seen here.  register_argc_argv = On

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use $_SERVER['argv'][1];   rather than $_SERVER['argv'];